# Stop user from typing before generated text

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, user-input

I am writing a text editor in WPF (using C#) that simulates a chat program using a RichTextBox. When the user presses enter, the relevant username is automatically inserted on the next line. However, if the user types fast enough, alternating between enter and other key presses, their text can appear before the generated username. Here is a screenshot that might demonstrate this better: http://oi62.tinypic.com/fusv1j.jpg

The problem used to be a lot worse, and after searching around I tried manually setting the caret position to the end after the insertion; unfortunately it's still possible to get text in before the initials if you go fast enough.

Here is my C# for the RichTextBox's KeyUp event, and the relevant helper methods:

```
private void textBoxEnterPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key != Key.Enter || initialsCheckBox.IsChecked == false)
        return;

    Chumhandle active = getActiveHandleBox().SelectedItem as Chumhandle;
    AppendText(mainTextBox, active.Initials + ": ", active.HexCode);

    TextPointer caretPos = mainTextBox.CaretPosition;
    caretPos = caretPos.DocumentEnd;
    mainTextBox.CaretPosition = caretPos;
}

private ComboBox getActiveHandleBox()
{
    if (activeBox == 1)
        return handleBox1;
    else
        return handleBox2;
}

public static void AppendText(RichTextBox box, string text, string color)
{
    BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
    TextRange tr = new TextRange(box.Document.ContentEnd, box.Document.ContentEnd);
    tr.Text = text;
    try
    {
        tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, bc.ConvertFromString(color));
    }
    catch (FormatException) { }

    box.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.ForegroundProperty, bc.ConvertFromString(color));
}
```

And the XAML for the RichTextBox:

```
<RichTextBox Name="mainTextBox" Grid.Row="3" FontFamily="Courier New" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" BorderThickness="0" KeyUp="textBoxEnterPressed">
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

Admittedly I'm not sure if this is possible to fix and I should just hope the user won't go that fast...

Comment: You have a _race_ with your box. Both want to handle Enter key: you in `textBoxEnterPressed` and `RichTextBox`  to add a new line. I'd stop this competition setting `AcceptsReturn` to `False`. It _shouldn't_ change anything here (unless you have a default button in your dialog) but I'd also set `e.Handled` to  `true`.

Comment: Oh boy, threading problems. Haha. Well that almost did it. The race is definitely fixed (I just had to have `textBoxEnterPressed` also insert a new line manually) but now if I put the cursor in the middle of the text and press enter, everything is appended to the very end, instead of at the cursor position as is intuitive. Makes me wonder if I'm missing out on some other functionality that `RichTextBox` automatically handles too.

Comment: No threads, it was done sequentially. You may even keep it as it was and set e.Handled to true (richtextbox won't handle enter if you did it). Actually I'd simply check to do something ONLY if you're at the very last line. Next step? Two boxes...one to view conversation and one to input text (as almost every chat does...what if someone else prints a message when you're still typing?)

Comment: I agree that using separate text boxes for input and the chat log is a good idea. You can style them in such a way that they appear to be the same control if that is the design you want, but trying to use a single text box instance is going to cause a lot of issues that you otherwise would never have to deal with.

Comment: Well, the thing is, this isn't an actual chat program; there's no online functionality. It's just a text editor that _simulates_ a specific fictional chat program, auto-formatting the document to look like a log from it. I also want to let the user insert text with enter presses _without_ this auto-formatting (that's what the check against `initialsCheckBox` is doing). I tried setting `mainTextBox.AcceptsReturn` back to true while keeping `e.Handled = true;` but that didn't fix the race anymore.

Comment: So... You want your user to be able to edit already written text, without adding the initials in that case, I assume?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. But if the user presses enter at any time, as long as `initialsCheckBox` is checked and regardless of cursor position, it should insert a line break as well as the initials.

Comment: But your forcing the opposite. Whenever the user presses enter, you append the initials at the end of your text and then move the caret to the end of your document. Instead of inserting it wherever the text caret was.

Comment: ...Oh yeah, huh. Hmm. Well, that's a totally different problem, now that I think about it. The race issue was solved so I think I'll just try and figure out the appending issue on my own. Thanks for all your help guys!

Comment: I just copied your code and I'm toying with it :P I'll post whatever I get from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've toyed a bit with your code, and this is what I managed:

```
    private void textBoxEnterPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Enter)
            return;

        // ADDED THIS TO SIMULATE AcceptsReturn = True
        if (initialsCheckBox.IsChecked == false)
        {
            AppendText(mainTextBox, Environment.NewLine, "#000000");
            return;
        }

        Chumhandle active = getActiveHandleBox().SelectedItem as Chumhandle;

        // ADDED Environment.NewLine TO INSERT LINE BREAKS
        AppendText(mainTextBox, Environment.NewLine + active.Initials + ": ", active.HexCode);

        // COMMENTED THIS BECAUSE IT WAS FORCING UNWANTED BEHAVIOR
        //TextPointer caretPos = mainTextBox.CaretPosition;
        //caretPos = caretPos.DocumentEnd;
        //mainTextBox.CaretPosition = caretPos;
    }

    public static void AppendText(RichTextBox box, string text, string color)
    {
        BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();

        // INSTEAD OF USING box.Document, I'VE USED box.Selection TO INSERT
        // THE TEXT WHEREVER THE CURSOR IS (OR IF YOU HAVE TEXT SELECTED)
        TextRange tr = new TextRange(box.Selection.Start, box.Selection.End);
        tr.Text = text;
        try
        {
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, bc.ConvertFromString(color));
        }
        catch (FormatException) { }

        // I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHAT THIS IS DOING SO I KEPT IT -_^
        box.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(RichTextBox.ForegroundProperty, bc.ConvertFromString(color));

        // FINALLY, I SET THE CARET TO THE END OF THE INSERTED TEXT
        box.CaretPosition = tr.End;
    }
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, once I switched `mainTextBox.AcceptsReturn` to false and used that instead, both problems are 100% fixed! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: Glad I could help :) Yeah, I forgot to mention the `AcceptsReturn` thing hehe (kudos to @AdrianoRepetti)

Answer (score 1):

Adriano Repetti got it in the comments; I had to turn off AcceptsReturn for the text box and handle inserting new lines on enter presses myself.

> You have a race with your box. Both want to handle Enter key: you in textBoxEnterPressed and RichTextBox to add a new line. I'd stop this competition setting AcceptsReturn to False. It shouldn't change anything here (unless you have a default button in your dialog) but I'd also set e.Handled to true.